# Drag and drop interface

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, drag-and-drop

I am trying to make a drag and drop interface like the one you have in visio for example. So you can drag objects out of a library on the field.

Is there a function to make this or do I have to code this all by myself?

Thank you,
Jerodev.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is good explanation of drag and drop: [Two ListBoxes - Drag and Drop Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/LarryDragAndDrop.aspx)

Comment: I am using a listview so I can use images to drag and drop, but I don't seem to be able to drag them out of the listview.

Answer (score 2):

As other people have noted: DragDrop, DragOver, DragLeave and DragEnter are your friends here. But don't forget to enable "AllowDrop" on the item that will receive the data. Here's a second great example: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/drag-and-drop-example.htm

This is for files, but you can easily see how the idea works, adjust the DataFormat in GetDataPresent to be whatever it is that you're dragging into your object, and off you go!

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using WPF there is a fantastic tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part2.aspx). It's a four-part series to creating a "designer canvas" in WPF.  Part two implements drag-and-drop functionality from a tool-box.  It's very well written and in the end you will get a user interface that is very much like Visio.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are methods available to make it easy for you to implement, look for DragDrop, DragEnter, DragOver