# Drag and drop interface for SQL database table mapping, dotnet core

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, drag-and-drop, .net-core

Have this problem, that I can't get my head around.
I have absolutely no idea where to start with this.

I have these two simplified tables (MSSQL):

```
Table 1
-------

ID    |    LetterCode
---------------------
1     |    ABC
2     |    DEF
3     |    GHI

Table 2
-------

ID    |    NumberCode    |    MappedTo    |    ConcatCode
----------------------------------------------------------
1     |    123           |                |
2     |    456           |                |
3     |    789           |                |
```

What I need to build is an web interface (GUI, site is built using dotnet core) where a user will have two panels:

- Left panel will display contents of Table 1
- Right panel will display contents of Table 2

I need a user to be able to drag the letter code from left panel, and drop it into 'MappedTo' column in the right panel.

When this happens I need to save the letter code in table 2 and create the concatenated code in ConcatCode column.

So for example if we dragged DEF code from left panel to right panel line 1, we would end up with this:

```
ID    |    NumberCode    |    MappedTo    |    ConcatCode
----------------------------------------------------------
1     |    123           |      DEF       |    123DEF
```

I wish I had some code to show but I have no idea how to bite this.

I believe the drag and drop interface can be achieved using jQuery and saving to the database can be achieved through Ajax.

I have found articles that mention this functionality somewhat, like this desktop app: [Drag and drop interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124349/drag-and-drop-interface) but that is not very helpful in my case.

Closest to the answer is this question:
[Drag and drop contents from one table to another using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422722/drag-and-drop-contents-from-one-table-to-another-using-jquery)

With jsfiddle example here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/Kzf62/18/)

I do not have resources to use Telerik Ui solution. So my question is, is there another library that already does this and I can use, if not I would really appreciate some hints on where to start with this.

Comment: I think the key here is to try to read the line you are dragging from the and the line you are dropping in drop event. 
If you can do this, you can manually populate the new table with the data. After this you only need to delete the first line you dont need...
You might need to make each row as a drop container.
Those are just thoughts, I never implemented that. Hope it helps